# How to fix Blogdown::serve_site() timeout error?

Tags: r-markdown, blogdown

I have tried the solutions I found online for this, but none of them seem to work...

Even after installing blogdown from github and updating hugo, I get a timeout error.
`remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')`
`blogdown::update_hugo()`

That is, when I run `blogdown::serve_site` I get this error:

`Launching the server via the command: C:\Users\Master\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe server --bind 127.0.0.1 -p 4321 --themesDir themes -t hugo-future-imperfect -D -F --navigateToChanged ERROR: The process "10244" not found. Error: It took more than 30 seconds to launch the server. There may be something wrong. The process has been killed. If the site needs more time to be built and launched, set options(blogdown.server.timeout) to a larger value.`

Is there another way to fix this?
What is causing this error?

Thanks!

Comment: What if you run `rmarkdown::render_site()` I would maybe open up a new project session and copy your code. Can are you able to run the example site with Blogdown? Also maybe just making the server timeout value larger like the error suggests if you have a large site

Comment: If you were truly using the dev version of **blogdown**, the error message should be different. After you `remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')`, you need to restart R. You may also see the session info `xfun::session_info('blogdown')` and verify if you have successfully installed the dev version of **blogdown**.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem on Kubuntu 20.10. I installed latest blogdown and hugo serveral days ago. I have blogdown 0.21.47 and hugo 0.79.0 on Kubuntu. Finally, I found a method to fix it.

1. Close Rstudio
2. Open terminal
3. Enter directory of your website
4. Execute `hugo server -D`
5. Press `Ctrl C` to stop
6. Open Rstudio
7. Click `Addin -> BLOGDOWN -> Serve Site`

I don't know why it works or whether it works in your case. Please test it and let us know whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same problem.

`blogdown::serve_site()`

wont work:

> Error: It took more than 30 seconds to launch the server. An error might have occurred with hugo. You may run blogdown::build_site() and see if it gives more info. If the site is very large and needs more time to be built, set options(blogdown.server.timeout) to a larger value.

although `blogdown::build_site()` works smoothly. The `blogdown::serve_site()` function works fine for a newly created project/website.

For repository see [here](https://github.com/JochemTolsma/homepage).

Not sure if it is a **blogdown**, **hugo** or **academic theme** issue.

```
sessionInfo()

R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] servr_0.20

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5       rstudioapi_0.13  knitr_1.30       magrittr_2.0.1   mnormt_2.0.2     pbivnorm_0.6.0  
 [7] R6_2.5.0         rlang_0.4.9      tools_4.0.3      tmvnsim_1.0-2    xfun_0.19        htmltools_0.5.0 
[13] yaml_2.2.1       digest_0.6.27    lavaan_0.6-7     bookdown_0.21    processx_3.4.5   later_1.1.0.1   
[19] promises_1.1.1   ps_1.4.0         evaluate_0.14    rmarkdown_2.5    blogdown_0.21.50 compiler_4.0.3  
[25] stats4_4.0.3     jsonlite_1.7.1   httpuv_1.5.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on. Installing "go" (https://golang.org/doc/install) helped - this was missing after my clean install of big sur.